# Can every simple closed curve be approximated by a simple closed poligonal?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

So, I am trying to prove that , if $C$ is a closed simple curved in $\mathbb{R}^2$ parametrized by a regular $\gamma:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ then there exists a $\delta>0$ so that, if $a=t_0 < t_1<...<t_N=b$ is a partition of [a,b] so that $t_i - t_{i-1} \leq \delta$ then the poligonal $\mathcal{P}$ which joins the points $\gamma(t_0),\gamma(t_1),...,\gamma(t_N)$ (in that order) is also simple and closed.

My guess is that there exists an $\varepsilon$ so that $\forall x \in C$, $ (B(x,\varepsilon)\cap C)$ is connected and then, as $\gamma$ is uniformly continuous, $\exists \delta$ so that $d_{\infty} (C,\mathcal{P})<\varepsilon$ and then, choosing the right $\varepsilon$ so that this neighbourhood of the curve where the poligonal lives doesn't intersect itself,and we are done. However, I don't see how to prove that this $\varepsilon$ exists.